# kafka machines in the cluster and kafka comunications

Tags: kafka

We have kafka cluster with 3 kafka brokers nodes and 3 zookperes servers

kafka version - 10.1 ( hortonworks )

from my understanding since all meta data is located on the zookeeper servers , and kafka brokers are using this data ( kafka talk with zookeeper server via port 2181 )

I just wondering if each kafka machine talk with other kafka in the cluster , or maybe kafka are get/put the data only on/from the zookeepers servers ?

So dose kafka service need to communicate with other kafka in the cluster ? , Or maybe kafka machines get all is need only from the zookeepers server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kafka brokers have to be able to communicate with each other.
Zookeeper is only used for metadata ([broker registration](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#impl_zkbroker), [topics](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#impl_zktopic), partitions, leader election), messages are replicated directly between Kafka brokers.